# Closing Parenthesis Beep in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, beep

this is really getting on my nerves and, after too much Googling, I haven't found a satisfactory fix for it.

If I begin to type in code using XCode 4.6, for instance:

```
float x = y + z
```

(my caret is just after the z) and then decide that what I really want is `float x = ceilf(y + z);` and I begin the modification by typing the closing parenthesis, XCode 4 beeps at me.  The parentheses aren't balanced, but I'm well aware of that.  I want to turn off this annoying beep, without making it system-wide.

Any solutions?

Comment: You may have an earlier syntax error.

Comment: XCode makes noises?  How uncouth.  Especially if one is sharing an office. Personally I have `System Preferences/Sound` `Alert Volume` =0 and `Play user interface sounds effects` unchecked. I never hear any annoying error beeps anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any way to edit this from within Xcode.  It is registered as an `alert sound`.  It works just like if you tried to close out of `Finder` with `cmd + q`.  It is handled on a system level.

You can, however, disable all of these alert sounds.

Step 1:  Go to `system preferences`.

[image: System Preferences]

Step 2: Open up the `Sound` menu.

[image: Sound Menu]

Step 3: Drag the little arrow of `Alert Volume` to 0.

[image: Alert Volume]

That is all that is technically necessary to disable the alert you hear when you type `}`, `)`, or `]` without a prior opening brace/bracket.  Some others also like to uncheck `Play user interface sound effects` because it removes some other annoying beeps and buzzes.

It is on the same page as the alert volume:

[image: Play user interface sound effects]

Comment: Seems a little clunky to me - disable *everything*? I guess if there's no other way...

Comment: Unfortunately I have not come across a better alternative in my two years of Xcode use.  If anyone has a better way i'd love to hear it.

Comment: Somehow I made it quit beeping without killing all sound effects - but I'm not sure how :(

Comment: Let us all know! :-)  Thanks, MrHappyAsthma, seems like overkill, and I'm worried that one day the muted beep won't be able to save me somewhere else... but rock 'n' roll: bye bye beeps!